# Como pasar un numero por un parámetro de la función?

Tags: sql-server

He buscado de todo modo hacer esto, pero no puedo. 
Lo que quiero es solo pasar un numero que sería un Id de un cliente y que me ejecute la función trayéndome de la BD según ese Id(en el where)

El objetivo es:

**"Crea una función que diga    la  cantidad    de  chequeo que ha  tenido  un  determinado cliente."**

Estas son algunas tablas:

```
Chequeo      Autos             Cliente           MarcaA
-------      -------          ----------        --------
IdChequeo    IdAuto           IdCliente          IdMarca
IdParte      Matricula        Nombre             Nombre
IdMecanic    IdAgen           Cedula             Modelo
Fecha        NoPuertas        Telefono           Pais
IdAuto       Color            Direccion          IdAuto
             IdCliente







CREATE FUNCTION CHEQUEO(@IdClient int)
return INT

AS
BEGIN
SELECT Cliente.IdCliente, 
   Cliente.Nombre,
   COUNT(Autos.IdCliente) AS Chequeos_Realizados

 FROM Cliente
 INNER JOIN    Autos ON Cliente.IdCliente = Autos.IdCliente
 INNER JOIN    Chequeo ON Autos.IdAuto = Chequeo.IdAuto
 INNER JOIN   MarcaA ON Autos.IdAuto = MarcaA.IdAuto
 WHERE Cliente.IdCliente = @IdClient
 GROUP BY Cliente.Nombre,Cliente.IdCliente,Autos.IdCliente
 END
```

No se que mas hacer, que falta.La sentencia del select la hice a pura lucha.Como le paso el parámetro?

La sentencia SELECT por si sola funciona y hace lo que quiero,siempre y cuando le quite todo eso de "function".

Comment: te saludo y te comento, llevas tiempo en la plataforma para saber que el código va como texto y no como imagen, menos foto; edita esto y has lo que te pido por favor

Comment: El parámetro de la función es `@IdCliente`, pero en la consulta usas otra variable inexistente `@id`

Comment: Después de dos años y medio en el sitio supongo que ya estarás familiarizado que una imagen no ayuda a que tu problema sea resuelto

Comment: Pero esa consulta tira error? ese group by esta mal, autos.idcliente no deberia formar parte del mismo... y la mayoria de esos joins no tienen sentido.

Comment: @gbianchi Amigo yo tengo que traer datos de varias tablas.                      
 • Crea una función que diga la cantidad de chequeo que ha tenido un determinado cliente.

Comment: A ver.. Pasar un parametro a un funcion es lo que estas haciendo. Podes aclarar mucho mejor esto y explicar cual es el problema? ese query, asi como esta, no va a funcionar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero plantearte algunas cosas que te van ayudar:
No es return, es returns. Y no es de tipo int ya que tu consulta no devuelve un solo valor entero, sino mucho datos. Y al final te faltó retornar el resultado.

Otra cosa que también es importante resaltar es que si devuelve múltiples valores(con forma de tabla) la función ya no es escalar, sino una función de tabla o de tabla en línea, al cambiar el tipo de función su estructura cambia. Te dejo tu ejemplo como una función de tabla en línea(claro, asumiendo lo que dices que la consulta funciona correctamente) :

```
CREATE FUNCTION CHEQUEO(@IdClient int)
returns table

AS
return (
    SELECT Cliente.IdCliente, 
    Cliente.Nombre,
    COUNT(Autos.IdCliente) AS Chequeos_Realizados

    FROM Cliente
    INNER JOIN    Autos ON Cliente.IdCliente = Autos.IdCliente
    INNER JOIN    Chequeo ON Autos.IdAuto = Chequeo.IdAuto
    INNER JOIN   MarcaA ON Autos.IdAuto = MarcaA.IdAuto
    WHERE Cliente.IdCliente = @IdClient
    GROUP BY Cliente.Nombre,Cliente.IdCliente,Autos.IdCliente
   )
```

Comment: Hugo Tirado  Como llamo la función?

Comment: Hugo Tirado Bueno ya se como se llama,gracias por tu ayuda amigo.Ahora me has motivado a investigar acerca de las funciones escalares,de tablas,de agregado.........

Comment: No pude conectarme antes para responder al primer comentario... Es un tema muy interesante y solucionan muchos problemas que normalmente se hacen del lado del cliente. Es mejor enviar un solo parámetro a la función y realizar el cálculo en el mismo gestor que tener que cargar todo ese proceso al sistema que lo requiera.